# Unable to calculate the sum of prime numbers below 2 million

Tags: objective-c, boolean, sum, primes, nested-loops

I'm doing the Euler's Method project to find the sum of prime numbers below 2 million and I'm struggling. Here is the code I'm using. When I calculate the sum below 10 and the sum below 50 I'm getting the right value, but where I'm calculating the sum below 2 million project Euler is saying my solution is incorrect. Any ideas?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        int p = 2, d, total;
        BOOL isPrime;
        total = 0;
        NSLog(@"%i ", p);
        for ( p = 3; p < 2e6; p += 2){
            isPrime = YES;

            for ( d = 3; isPrime == YES && d < p; d += 2)
               if ( p % d == 0)
                   isPrime = NO;

            if (isPrime == YES){
                NSLog(@"%i ", p);
                        total  += p ;}
        }
        NSLog(@"total = %i", total + 2);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function sums the primes less than *n* using the Sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
function sumPrimes(n)
    sum := 0
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
            sum := sum + p
            for i from p * p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
    return sum
```

I'll leave it to you to translate to Objective-C with a suitable data type. For *n* = 2000000, this should run in one or two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes. The first being that you're overflowing. Use a long instead of an int. The second thing is just a performance boost. Change your for loop from p < 2e6, to p*p <= 2e6. This way you rule out all numbers above the square root of 2e6. Fix those problems and you'll be good to go. Good luck!